# I downloaded VS 2019 Enterprise. When I tried compile .net core 3.0 project, I got a problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

In project properties in Target framework I don’t see .net core 3 option to choose.
In VS 2019 preview I normaly can choose it and build the project.

NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.
Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core

Having the same issue. I've downloaded the latest preview and .net core 3.0 preview, ensured that "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK" is checked and I'm still failing to compile the solution.

Also I have Installed core sdk 3.0 and Enable Preview from Options settings in Vs 2019

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 was release a month ago. Don't use the RC to begin with. As for the error, it means you haven't installed the .NET Core 3 SDK. Install the *release* version of [VS 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and the latest version of the [.NET Core 3 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)

Comment: I have Installed the Latsest Version of .Net Core SDK 3.0 when I bulid My Project it does't Restore Nu Packages

Comment: And yet you use an *old* version of Visual Studio 2019. Install the RTM version. There have been a couple of updates in the last month too

Answer (score 6):

*note 1)* this answer was given prior of OP noting

> and Enable Preview from Options settings in Vs 2019

as it is informative, I'll leave it for reference.

---

*note 2)* VS2019 was fully released a while ago, I recommend you'll get it first. You can get it here:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

---

To let preview versions show up in VS 2019, you should enable **Use previews of the .NET Core SDK** under "`Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> .NET Core`":

[image]

Developers using VS2019 Version 16.1.0 or later can find this option under "`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features`".

Comment: The OP says that the RC version is installed instead of the RTM

Comment: Alreday I have checked Use Preview of the .net Core SDK

Comment: Please install the full vs2019, and perhaps you'll need to reboot. Worked for me out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is Solved By Restarting the Visual Studio ** After Check enable **Use previews of the .NET Core SDK under "tools -> options":**

Thanks All of you!

[image: Solved]

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

The option has moved (in Visual Studio 2019).

> Tools // Options // Environment // Preview Features //// Use previews
>   of the .NET Core SDK (requires restart)

[image: Use Previews of the .NET Core SDK]

```
# My version of VS 2019 just to be complete
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
Version 16.2.0
```

My original error message:

> NETSDK1045    The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core
>   3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. MyProjectName   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.801\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets    137